# Are these two arrays equal? If not, how can I make them equal?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm newish to programming and Python, and this is my first question on Stack Overflow:

I'm trying to compare some tic-tac-toe boards to see if they are equal. I'm given some of the type:

```
    [[' ' ' ' ' ' ]
     [' ' ' ' ' ' ]
     [' ' 'x' ' ' ]]
```

which is a 2d string array as I understand it, and I want to compare it to some I've generated. I've tried to generate all possible states using the following code:

```
    import itertools
    p = ['o', 'x', ' ']
    itertools.product(p, repeat = 9)
    layouts = np.array([[i[0:3],i[3:6],i[6:9]] for i in 
    itertools.product(p, repeat = 9)])
```

which results in some 'boards' looking like this (I know this isn't a legitimate outcome):

```
    [[['o', 'o', 'o'],
    ['o', 'o', 'o'],
    ['o', 'o', 'o']]
```

Sorry if this is a stupid question but I can't figure out if these are of the same format. I thought I was creating a string array but they don't seem to match. If they're not, how can I make a 2d string using my code for generating all possible board layouts?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Your two example boards both have syntax errors, so it's hard to guess at what's going on. Can you create a [mcve] that shows two boards comparing unequal when you expect they should be equal, or vice versa?

Comment: Hi, what do you mean about syntax errors? They appear exactly as typed in my output. I see there is an extra square bracket however

Comment: In your first board, there should be commas between the lists in the first list. While you can type the strings directly adjacent to each other, the interpreter will concat them. In the second board, the number of opening and closing brackets should match.

Comment: The first array is the one given by my teacher in the starter code for this task. It is of that form

Comment: Then the assignment itself is faulty.

Comment: It should be properly something like this: `[[' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' '], [' ', ' ', ' ']]`

Comment: @Querenker thanks. I'm still not sure about that format but I guess this isn't something you can help with

Comment: I am pretty sure, the format in my last comment is right (you can add linebreaks if you like, but comments don't allow that). The other version would be without the commas between the strings. That would be evaluated to a concatenated string. This would work as well, but then the extra list around it is superfluous.

Comment: Oh right i see. Thanks very much